# User getSessionToken() Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm attempting to create a login flow for Parse using phone number verification. The idea is that users of an iOS app enter their phone number, receive a code via SMS, then enter that code to login. No email/username/password required.

The critical piece is getting the session token to then use the `become` method. Here is my (abbreviated, doesn't include code verification) cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('signInUser', function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var phone = request.params.phone;
  var verificationCode = request.params.verificationCode;
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.equalTo('phone',  phone)
  query.first().then(function(user) {
    if (!user) {
      response.error('User does not exist');
    }

    var token = user.getSessionToken();
    console.log("Token: " + token);
    response.success('Token: ' + token);
   })
})
```

`token` is always returning as `undefined`. According to the docs, using `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` should allow me to accomplish what I want to do but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the master key directly in query:

```
query.first({ useMasterKey: true }).then(...);
```